# How to add reference to external stylesheet using iText and htmltopdf

Tags: c#, css, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I have a console app that generates a PDF from HTML. HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="html\\somestyle.css" /> </head>
```

If I include the styles directly in the HTML, using `<style>` tag, then they show up in the PDF. But I need to use external stylesheet.

The folder structure is like this:

```
***Task_ABC (folder)
******Task.exe
******HTML (folder)
*********template.html
*********somestyle.css
```

The console app is scheduled via Windows Task Scheduler.

If I run the app from command prompt manually, the `html\\sometyle.css` syntax works and styles show up in PDF.

But when Task Scheduler runs it, styles don't show up in PDF.

I have tried `somestyle.css` as well as `html/somestyle.css` syntax and they don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the HTML as a file stream to `HtmlConverter` instead of passing it as a file then the resources will be resolved against the current working directory. This may be the cause of the problem in processing your file in another environnment.

You can set the `baseUri`, i.e. the uri which all the resources in HTML will be resolved against in `ConverterProperties`:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(fileInputStream, fileOutputStream, new ConverterProperties().setBaseUri(baseUri));
```

The `baseUri` should point to the directory containing your `html` directory. You can also freely use `html/somestyle.css` link syntax, not necessary to use Windows-style path.

Comment: `baseUri` will be the folder where the executable resides? Something like `c:\apps\task_abc`?

Comment: @joym8 It's the folder containing your resources, in your case containing the `html` directory. You can think of base uri as the prefix which will be appended to the resource paths in HTML

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me: `new ConverterProperties().setBaseUri( AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "css");` where css is a folder under the main project directory.